Proving that a Curve Intersects Itself
Suppose that $\gamma\colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map satisfying the following: $\gamma(0) = (r, 0)$ and $\gamma(1) = (r, n)$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ (i.e. $r > 0$) and where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $n \geq 2$. Let $C_{1}$ denote the image of $\gamma_{1}$, $C_{1} = \gamma([0,1])$. Define $C_{2}$ as follows:  $C_{2} = \{(r, s) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \mid (r, s) = \gamma(t) + (0,1) \text{ for  some }  t \in [0,1]\}$
(i.e. $C_{2}$ is $C_{1}$ shifted up in $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ by one unit along with the $\mathbb{R}$-axis).
In what follows, $p_{1}: \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ will denote a projection from $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ to the first component, $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $p_{2}: \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will denote the projection from $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ to the second component, $\mathbb{R}$.
I believe we should be able to show that $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ must intersect ($C_{1} \cap C_{2} \neq \emptyset$) as follows:

If we join the line-segment $L = \{(r, t) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R} \mid 0 \leq t \leq n\}$ to $C_{1}$, then we obtain a closed curve (albeit one that might interest itself). Let’s call this curve $C_{1}’$.

Since $C_{1}'$ is compact, it is wholly contained in a disk of radius $R$, $C_{1}' \subset B_{R}(0)$, where $B_{R}(0) = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}, x^{2} + y^{2} \leq R^{2} \}$. Therefore, $B_{R}(0)^{C} \subset (C_{1}')^{C}$, so that $(C_{1}')^{C}$ contains at least one unbounded path-connected component. Further, the boundary of $(C_{1}')^{C}$ satisfies $\partial (C_{1}')^{C} = \bar{C_{1}'} \cap \bar{C_{1'}^{C}} = C_{1}' \cap \bar{C_{1}^{C}} \subset C_{1}'$, i.e. the boundary of the complement of $C_{1}'$ is a subset of $C_{1}'$ itself.

If the point $(r, 1)$ lives on $C_{1}$, then the conclusion that $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \neq \emptyset$ is obvious as in this case $\{ (r, 1) \} \subset C_{1} \cap C_{2}$. Note that it is always true that $(r, 1)$ lives on $C_{1}’$.

If we assume that $(r,1) \notin C_{1}$, then let $T$ denote the maximum value for which $\gamma(t) = (r, s) \in C_{1}$ for all $t \leq T$ i.e. $T = \sup \{ t \in [0, 1] p_{1}(\gamma(t_{1})) = r \text{ for ALL } t_{1} \leq t\}$. It is then clear from assumption that $T <1$ and from continuity of $\gamma$, we have $\gamma(T) = (r, s_{T}) \in C_{1}$ (note that we set $p_{2}(\gamma(T)) = s_{T}$).

It is then clear from definition that $(r, s_{T} + 1) \in C_{2}$.

This is where I am stuck: show that there is a point $(r_{1}, s_{1}) \in C_{2}$ with $r_{1} \neq r$ that is EITHER in a bounded path-connected componenet of $(C_{1}')^{C}$ OR is on $C_{1}'$ on itsef. Note that in the latter case, the assumption that $r_{1} \neq r$ impies that $(r_{1}, s_{1})$ is actually on $C_{1}$, so then we have $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \neq \emptyset$ because in this case $(r_{1}, s_{1}) \in C_{1} \cap C_{2}$.


6(a). Let $T_{L}$ denotes the smallest number larger than $T$ for which $p_{1}(\gamma(T_{L}) = r$. $\gamma(T_{L}) = (r, s_{L})$. It is clear that $T<T_{L}\leq 1$ and $s_{T}<s_{L}\leq n$. If $s_{L} = s_{T} + 1$, then from the definitions, we have $(r, s_{L}) \in C_{1} \cap C_{2}$, so we can automatically conclude that $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \neq \emptyset$.
6(a, i) Case 1: If $s_{L} > s_{T} + 1$, then the region $B_{1}$ bounded by $L' = \{ (r, s) , s_{T} \leq t \leq s_{L} \}$ (which is a subset of $L$) and $\gamma([T, T_{L}])$ is a bounded path-connected component of the complement of $C_{1}$, $(C_{1}')^{C}$. Note further, that if $T < t < T_{L}$, then continuity of $\gamma$ implies that $p_{1}(\gamma(t)) - r$ does not change sign, i.e. $\operatorname{sgn}(p_{1}(\gamma(t)) - r)$ is constant. Let $m =  \inf \{dist((r, s_{T}+1), \gamma(t)),  t \in [T, T_{L}] \}$. Again, by continuity of the curve $\gamma$, if $T_{1}=T+\delta$ for $\delta$ sufficiently small, then $dist((\gamma(T_{1}) + (0,1)), (r, s_{T}+1)) < m$. Let $(r_{1}, s_{1}) = \gamma(T_{1})$ and consider the line segment from $(r, s_{T} + 1)$ to $(r_{1}, s_{1})$. For any $T<t<T_{1}$, the sign of $p_{1}(\gamma(t) + (0,1)) - r = p_{1}(\gamma(t)) - r$ is constant and the same same as the sign of $p_{1}(\gamma(t)) - r$ for any $t \in [T, T_{L}]$. This means that the point $(r_{1}, s_{1})$ lies on the same side of the Line $l = \{ (r, s), s \in \mathbb{R} \}$ as $\gamma((T, T_{L})$ (i.e. either ) Continuity shows that this implies that the line segment from $(r, s_{T} +1)$ to $(r_{1}, s_{1})$ does not intersect the line $L$ as otherwise there would be a point on this line segment where $p_{1}  = r$
Also, note that for some curves, we can just let $T_{1} = T + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ small enough, but this is NOT always true.

Let $T_{\mathrm{max}} = \sup \{t \in [0, 1] \mid (r, t) \in C_{1}\}$. It is clear from the assumptions that $T_{\mathrm{max}} \geq 2$ and from continuity of $\gamma$ that $(r, T_{\mathrm{max}}) \in C_{1}$. Further, $(r, t) \notin C_{1}$ for any $t > T_{\mathrm{max}}$.

It is also clear that $(r, T_{\mathrm{max}} + 1) \in C_{2}$ and the ray $L_{1} = \{(r, t) \mid t \geq T_{\mathrm{max}} + 1\}$ does not intersect $C_{1}’$; $L_{1} \cap C_{1}’ = \emptyset$. Therefore, the point $(r, T_{\mathrm{max}} + 1)$ must belong to the unbounded component of $(C_{1}')^{C}$.

Since $C_{2}$ is a continuous curve joining $(r_{1}, T_{1})$ in a bounded component of $(C_{1})'$ to  $(r, T_{\mathrm{max}} + 1)$ in the unbounded component, it must intersect $C_{1}’$, at least a porition of which bounds $(C_{1}')^{C}$. Since $C_{1}’$ and $C_{1}$ are identical off of the line $L = \{(r, t) \mid 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$, it follows that $C_{2}$ must intersect $C_{1}$: $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \neq \emptyset$.


Any assistance in the filling in the details of number 6, where I am stuck or providing some more details concluding that $C_{2}$ intersecting $C_{1}’$ implies $C_{2}$ intersects $C_{1}$ in number 9 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Another idea I also had was to consider vertical line segments that intersect and $C_{1}$ and use a pigeon-hole argument based on where and how many times $C_{1}$ intersects $L$. I know this is vague, but it might lead to a more simpler proof. More generally, I also believe that if $\gamma$ has $\gamma(0) = (r_{\gamma}, 0)$ and $\gamma(r_{\gamma}, s_{\gamma})$ for some $s_{\gamma} > 0$, then the shift up the curve up by $\frac{s_{\gamma}}{2}$ units, $C_{2} = \{ (r, s) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} | (r, s) = \gamma(t) + (0, \frac{s_{\gamma}}{2}))$ should intersect $C_{2}$. Again, any advice or insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Ad Step 2: The Jordan Curve Theorem does not apply as you state it, no. For a start, take a figure-eight; it's complement has three components, two of which are bounded. Somewhat counterintuitively, it can also happen that the number of components is less than for the JCT: There is a continuous surjection $[0, 1] \to [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, whose complement is then obviously $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ which is connected and unbounded (although you must have at exactly one unbounded component in every case).

Ad Step 5: This is not clear. It would be clear (and for that matter, true) if you knew that $(r, T) \in C_1$, but you haven't shown this; $T$ is defined as a supremum. It is true, but I do think you need a limit argument.

Ben Steffan; it should be clear from continuity that $(r, T) \in C_{1}$ from continuity and limits. I left out the doctor concentrate on the rest of the proof.

Ben Steffan,  for step 2, I suppose I suppose it should suffice for $C_{2}’$ to be the boundary of one unbounded component. Step 6 could then become the following : show that there is an element $(r_{1}, T_{1})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ that is EITHER in the interior of the bounded component of which $C_{1}’$ is the boundary OR an element of $C_{1} = C_{1}’ - L$.

@RobertAbramovic Why did you change accounts? What's $C_2'$? In either case, there's no reason to suppose that $C_1'$ is the boundary of the unbounded component or the boundary of a bounded component. I would hope that the boundary of any component of the complement is at least a subset of $C_1'$, but I don't see a proof of that directly.

@BenSteffan, I don’t believe I changed accounts. I think I made a typo when I type $C_{2}’$. It should have been $C_{1}’$. I believe you mentioned earlier that an extension of the Jordan Curve Theorem would indicate that $C_{1}’$, being a closed curve, albeit one that might have self-intersections, would have a complement containing an ubounded component whose boundary in EITHER all of $C_{1}’$ OR a subset of $C_{1}’$, like you stated.

@RobertAbramovic The account you're posting these comments from is not the account that asked the question. As for the JCT, I've only said that the complement must have exactly one unbounded component, but nothing about boundaries.

Looking at this now, however, it's actually not hard to see it's true: Since the image of any curve $C$ is compact, we have $\partial C^{\mathrm{C}} = \overline{C} \cap \overline{C^{\mathrm{C}}} = C \cap \overline{C^{\mathrm{C}}} \subseteq C$ (here ${{-}}^{\mathrm{C}}$ is the complement).

@BenSteffan. Thanks for the clarification!

@BenSteffan. I updated the question based on your comments. I believe the details of all steps except 6 and 9 should be clear and true. These two steps are where I am stuck.
